# Need help with basic armature stuff

Tags: animation, armature, bezier-curves

I´m a newbie with blender and this is probably very basic stuff I´m asking, but I really can´t get my head around this. I have a snakelike mesh I would like to slither in place like a wave but having two fixed points in the start and in the end of the mesh. How should I make this?  How do I make the fixed points? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You already have the snake mesh, create a bezier curve, bend it in edit mode so it creates the pattern in which you want to slither it. Add the Curve modifier to the snake and choose the bezier curve you just created for the modifier, play around with the axis parameters. Once you get it right just move the bezier curve up and down (or back and forth), you'll get the slither.

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, already.  The question required the two end points to be fixed. One way would be to add a couple of shape keys to curve, with fixed end points (pretty much simply a  mirror),  and animating via shape key instead of moving curve.

Comment: @batFINGER I tried 2 points: I selected all the vertices of the cuboid (snake) except the ends which need to be fixed at one place, I assigned 100 weight to those selected vertices (red in weight paint mode). In the curve modifier I selected the curve ( as usual) but this time also selected the Vertex group, theoretically it should work but it is giving me weird shape.